# jQuery: Is there a way to convert date for jQuery Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using two different datepickers on my site at present, and I'd like to instead just use jQuery's Datepicker.

At present, this is the current format that I am passing through to our backend API:
[image]
[image]

However, I'd really like to append the datepicker to this input field. By using the jQuery datepicker, however, my date turns to this, which is invalid value to send to backend API:

[image]
[image]

Any idea on how I'd convert the format "07/16/14" into "Wed Jul 16 2014" on close of the datepicker?

Comment: date formats are all outlined in the docs  http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to utilize the various options available in the `dateFormat` options. Full reference is available on the jQueryUI website - http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats and the API site - http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

The format of `D M dd yy` should give you what you want.

Sample code:
`$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "D M dd yy" });`

Comment: When I use that, it appends 2014 on the end: `$('.value').val()
"Thu Jul 17 20142014"` . Any suggestions on how to correct?

Comment: @iamryandrake Try `{ dateFormat: "D M dd yy"}` "yy" indicates a 4 digit year [http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate]

Comment: Great! So that works now. However, if I type in "07/24/14" and hit Enter, the date doesn't change and remains in that format. Is there a way to format it into above date when I focus out of the input field? Thanks so much for your help!